# why angular dont have safeApply?

Tags: angularjs

If the user manually applies somewhere `$scope.$apply()` it shows error in the case of digest is already running. If *angularjs* developer did already know about it then would they have provided something like safeApply ?

Although we can create our own safeApply.

Answer (score 3):

You should always know whether you are inside a `$digest` or no. So having a dedicated function shouldn't be needed.

Having said that, there is `$scope.$evalAsync` that should handle the problematic cases.

Note, some people would use `$scope.$$phase` private variable to check whether they are inside a `digest` or not but that's not a good solution. It's a hack for something that can be achieved by better architecture.

Comment: thanks sulthan for giving me guidence ..Really I was using $scope.$$phase to check whether i m inside cycle or not..